# Outlook calendar reshuffles my calendar group settings every time I boot up

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I just got a new laptop, and since then, my calendar groups are either empty or the members keep getting shuffled around (my own calendar keeps landing under "Shared Calendars" instead of defaulting to the top, for example).

My system settings were migrated to the new laptop 1:1 by IT, and this is the only bug which is happening, otherwise all my settings (e-mail folders, rules etc) are still fine. Regardless of how often I keep placing the group members in their respective groups, they disappear or reshuffle to another group every time I log on to my laptop - and some of the members appear in duplicate.

Is this a known problem, and is there a solution to fix the members in the groups I've created? Since migrating everything to Microsoft Teams, we no longer have PSTs, so I can't change it there...

Comment: Have you asked your company Exchange support persons?  I use Outlook 365 but individual and POP so no issues.

Comment: We're using the business version of Outlook 365, but it all worked fine until my laptop change - I've got a ticket open with IT but this is a low-priority case so I'm not expecting an answer any time soon... :-/